# Disable Word wrap in JTextPane

Tags: java, swing

I can't find an easy way to turn off word wrap in a JTextPane.  I can't use JTextArea because I need different colors for different text.  I have these big ugly lines that get uglier with word wrap turned on.

JTextArea has a setLineWrap() method, but I can't find it for JTextPane.  Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, I found an easy solution.  Put the JTextPane into the center of a JPanel with a Border layout.  Then, put the JPanel into a JScrollPane.

So, the hierarchy looks like this:

- JScrollPane
- JPanel (w/ Border Layout)
- JTextPane

JScrollPane contains everything below it and the JTextPane is inside of everything above it.

I'm not sure why this works, but it does.

Comment: I think the reason this works is because when the text pane is in a panel with BorderLayout (as center) which is in a ScrollPane, its preferred size grows to whatever the contents require (i.e. borderlayout gives it as much space as it wants and since it's in a scroll pane it can grow as much as it wants. When it was just in a panel or frame directly, its size was constrained by the size of the panel/frame. Once text length was > available length, the JTextPane started wrapping words to fit them in the available space (which was fixed).

Comment: Well said! (I have to put more words or SO won't let me post this comment)