# Java- JScrollPane : horizontal becomes vertical

Tags: java, jscrollpane

I'm using JFrame for the very 1st time and I have a problem when using a JScrollPane. 
I have 21 DNA sequences I need  to write, I created a JSplitPane to have the ID on the left and the sequences on the right. I wanted to put each sequence (about 1500 chars ) on 1 line . I'm sure a picture will be better than my explainations : the following pciture is exactly what I need and it works perfectly if I put the 15 first DNA sequences!

[picture 1 : expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jG4p2.png)

but if I add another one... that's a disaster : each sequence is writen on several lines and I lose almost completely the horizontal scroll : 
[picture 2 : result if I add another sequence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GsNI.png)

Here's the code :

```
public class FenetreAlignement extends JFrame {
  private JSplitPane split;
  private MyTextPane textPaneSeq =  new MyTextPane();
  private MyTextPane textPaneID =  new MyTextPane();
  private JScrollPane scroll;
  private JPanel panId = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());      
  private JPanel panSeq = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
  private ArbreAlignement arbre;
}

public FenetreAlignement(ArbreAlignement arbre) {
  this("ALignement multiple de sequences",300000,300000,false,arbre);
}

public FenetreAlignement(String titre, int largeur, int hauteur, boolean boolExit, ArbreAlignement arbre) {      
  this.arbre = arbre;       
  this.setTitle(titre);
  this.setSize(largeur,hauteur);
  /* centrage */
  this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  if(boolExit == true)
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
  else
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
  int taille;
  char c;
  HashMap<Integer,SequenceAlignement> sequencesInitiales = arbre.getSequences();
  ArrayList<String> seq = arbre.getResultatFinal();

  StyledDocument doc = textPaneSeq.getStyledDocument();
  StyledDocument docID = textPaneID.getStyledDocument();
  Color cA = new Color(64,128,255);
  Attribut styleA = new Attribut("Courier new",18,cA);
  Attribut styleT = new Attribut("Courier new",18,Color.PINK);
  Attribut styleG = new Attribut("Courier new",18,Color.CYAN);
  Attribut styleC = new Attribut("Courier new",18,Color.MAGENTA);
  Attribut styleDef = new Attribut("Courier new",18,Color.WHITE);
  try {
    for(String s : seq) {
      taille = s.length();
      for(int i = 0; i < taille; i++) {
      c = s.charAt(i); 
      if(c == 'A')
        doc.insertString(doc.getLength(),"A",styleA);
      else if(c == 'G')
        doc.insertString(doc.getLength(),"G",styleG);
      else if(c == 'C')
        doc.insertString(doc.getLength(),"C",styleC);   
      else if(c == 'T')
        doc.insertString(doc.getLength(),"T",styleT);   
      else
        doc.insertString(doc.getLength(),Character.toString(c),styleDef);       
    }
    doc.insertString(doc.getLength(),"\n\n\n",styleDef);
  }  
  catch(Exception e){}
  try {     
    for (HashMap.Entry<Integer, SequenceAlignement> entry :sequencesInitiales.entrySet()) {
      docID.insertString(docID.getLength(),entry.getValue().getId(),styleDefaut);
            docID.insertString(docID.getLength(),"\n\n\n",styleDefaut);
    }
  } 
  catch (BadLocationException e){}  
  scroll = new JScrollPane(textPaneSeq,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
  split = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, panId, panSeq);
  split.setDividerLocation(60);
  split.setRightComponent(scroll);
  split.setLeftComponent(textPaneID);
  this.getContentPane().add(split);
  this.setVisible(true);
}
```

I've already read many topics but nothing could fix the bug. I've also tried this :

```
public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
  return getUI().getPreferredSize(this).width <= getParent().getSize().width;
}
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help or any idea.

Comment: Your code does not compile

Comment: Can you show the code for MyTextPane class?

Comment: Maybe have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009787/disable-word-wrap-in-jtextpane). You could also use a JLabel with the text wrapped in <html> tags